# max() is returning 99 when 100 should be the highest in my list

Tags: python

```
def get_highs():
    atlTemps = open("tempsAtlanta2015.txt")
    highs = []
    highs = split_data(atlTemps, highs, 2)
    atlTemps.close()
    return highs

def split_data(lst, lst2, num):
    for i in lst:
        data = i.split(",")
        lst2.append(data[num])
    return lst2

def main():
    highs = get_highs()
    print(max(highs))
main()
```

I pulled these functions out of my main program to troubleshoot, and I seem to be having a problem with using max(). In the text document I am pulling information from the highest number returned by max() should be 100 but instead it is returning 99. I can index out 100 so I know for certain that 100 is contained in the list. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is part of the text file, the information is stored as `[month, day, high, low]`

```
7,29,99,76
7,30,98,76
7,31,96,73
8,1,93,71
8,2,96,68
8,3,98,71
8,4,99,69
8,5,100,71
8,6,90,72
…
```

Comment: I tried to fix the indentation but you may want to double check that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't converting the string representation of your integers to integers. So lexicographically `'99' > '100'`. As seen here:

```
>>> max(('99', '100'))
'99'
```

However converting them to ints:

```
>>> max((99, 100))
100
```

In your `split_data()` function you can:

```
def split_data(lst, lst2, num):
    for i in lst:
        data = i.split(",")
        lst2.append(data[num])
    return [int(element) for element in lst2]
```

Comment: Ohhh man, thank you very much!!!! That makes perfect sense!

Comment: @Javajojoe if this answer solves your problem, check the check box